# Cyrus with SASL authentication keeps appending hostname

Tags: cyrus

I am currently in the process of setting up a new Cyrus mailserver and running into quite a funny paradox. I am trying to use the auxprop pw_check mechanism to let Cyrus read /etc/sasldb2 for user authentication.

For some reason, when creating a new user, saslpasswd2 keeps appending my hostname to the username I am creating. This is in no way a problem, it only implies I will need to have my users login with username@mydomain.org.

This is where the fun starts. When I try to authenticate via an IMAP client to my Cyrus server, Cyrus logs 'badlogin: mydomain.org [127.0.0.1] plaintext pieter SASL(-13): user not found: checkpass failed'. Cyrus seems to strip off the @mydomain.org part, as it is configured to be the default hostname.

This leaves me in the predicament of being unable to create users that can authenticate to Cyrus. Has anyone else faced this problem?

Comment: I think @Steven's comment may help, but in case it doesn't could you update your post with the saslauthd commandline that is being used?

Comment: Add Mailbox Documentation: http://www.cyrusimap.org/docs/cyrus-imapd/2.3.16/install-admin-mb.php # cyradm

Answer (score 0):

In you cyrus config set `defaultdomain` to be the same as your local hostname.